# Images don't get displayed on Android with Ionic 3

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

My html file contains:

```
</ion-content>
<ion-content class="card-background-page">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-card ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event,item) ">
        <img src="{{item.image}}"/>
        <div class="card-title">{{item.title}}</div>
        <div class="card-subtitle">{{item.subTitle}}</div>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
```

the controller contains this code:

```
    this.items.push(
        {title:"Item 1",subTitle:"one",image:"assets/img/preview_1.png"},
{title:"Item 2",subTitle:"two",image:"assets/img/panorama_2.png"}
      )
```

it works well when running in the browser using `ionic serve`, but once built for Android (with the Ionic Cloud service) the images don't get displayed on the device.

I tried:

1)`./assets/img/panorama_2.png` instead of `assets/img/panorama_2.png`

2)`<img src="url({{item.image}})"/>` instead of `<img src="{{item.image}}"/>`

but still nothing

Comment: I assume you are in a page folder. So you need to go one folder back to access the pages folder and another to access the root folder.
`../../assets/img/panorama_2.png`

Comment: for my apps its just "assets/img.jpg" even if I am in the page folder. my assets-folder is on the same hierachy-level as the pages-folder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your assets are inside `src/assets/img` and not inside `www/assets/img`

Comment: Yes, I can confirm they are there